# How to find the average time per job id in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to find the average time per job id.

Below is the data

[image]

I tried this dax query

```
AverageTime =
AVERAGEX (
    VALUES ( Ratings[Date] ),
    CALCULATE ( AVERAGE ( Ratings[job_id] ) )
)
```

Data type of Date is **Time**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To calculate the average time per job_id, create a calculated column with the following DAX formula:

   ```
    Average Date = 
    var jo_id = 'Table'[job_ID]

   Return
   AVERAGEX( 
       FILTER(ALL('Table'), 'Table'[job_ID] = jo_id),
             'Table'[Date])
   ```
2. After creating the **Average Date column** set the data type to **Time** in the Column tools, and set the format as desired.
   [image]

You should have the desired result.

[image: Output]

[image: Another Output]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Just one add-on, we can use FORMAT to get this into date format instead of using the column tools.

Comment: Yes, you can use **Format** DAX  function to get the calculated column into *date/time* format

Answer (score 1):

I have obtain the result using the following formula, should be correct as you expected. Calculate method is not necessary since the table will filter the value base on id, :

```
= FORMAT(AVERAGE(Sheet2[date]),"HH:MM:SS")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is giving me the average time considering all the dates but not per id. Do we have to specify the id filter explicitly?

Comment: The result is calculated based on per ID, when you checking back the excel data manually, average time for ID 1 is 1.3 hrs, and ID 2 is 4.3 hrs. Any part is wrong? Unless you want to perform comparison then it is another story.

Comment: What is the chart you are planning to use,?

Comment: I am using the cards. I tried using your dax query but it is giving me the overall average instead of per ID

Comment: See my edited answer, you don't any formula to display specific ID, Simply drag the id into filter, then you can choose the ID you want, another option is add slicer.

Comment: I got it. Can you please tell me how to create a new column for average time per ID using DAX?

Comment: In such case, you need to create one table for unique Id then add column to calculate average time, no that much difficult once you know how to create unique ID in new table.